# PostgreSQL - How to select data between two dates, if max date is the future then returns null

Tags: postgresql

I have data that i need to build in line chart.
I got the dates and it's generated dynamically, E.g; 7 days, 1 month, 2 months, etc.
I need to count the data in each date, but when the date is a future it's still returns the data

```
select kolektor, nama, created_at
  from konstituen
 where paslon_id = '41'
   and periode = '2024'
   and kolektor = '3'
   and to_char(created_at,'mm/dd') between '02/28' and '03/31'
 order by created_at desc;
```

[image]

[image]

while now is 03/18, i expected that the data will returns empty. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30)?

Comment: please find the sample here: https://dbfiddle.uk/cq7ylijm

Comment: All the dates in your sample data in the fiddle are `between '02/23' and '03/31'`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is; i'm not sure am i really need to use this method or not. but my expectation is if the date is a future than the result must be empty. this data will displayed on line-chart. the x-axis will be a dates, and on each date will displaying maximum of counter for each kolektor. please find the image at my questions above for more clear clue. thanks

Comment: *if the date is a future* what does this mean? Which date? Edit your question and explain better what you want with sample data and expected results.

Comment: This `to_char(created_at,'mm/dd') between '02/28' and '03/31'` is going to find data for all rows that have dates starting with `'02/28' and '03/31'`, so there is concept of future(or past) as you are not including a `year`.

Comment: That should have been: *... so there is **no** concept of future(or past) ...*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a case statement that returns data when the date is between the first date and `current_date` (i.e., today).

Suppose you added data for future dates to your fiddle data linked above.

```
INSERT INTO "sample"("kolektor", "nama", "createdat") VALUES (3, 'ex1', '2023-03-17');
INSERT INTO "sample"("kolektor", "nama", "createdat") VALUES (3, 'ex2', '2023-03-18');
INSERT INTO "sample"("kolektor", "nama", "createdat") VALUES (5, 'ex3', '2023-03-19');
INSERT INTO "sample"("kolektor", "nama", "createdat") VALUES (6, 'ex4', '2023-03-20');
INSERT INTO "sample"("kolektor", "nama", "createdat") VALUES (5, 'ex5', '2023-03-21');
```

Then you can apply the logic under the select keyword:

```sql
select 
  kolektor,
  nama,
  to_char(createdat,'yyyy-mm-dd') createdat,
  case 
    when createdat between '2023-02-23' and CURRENT_DATE
    then kolektor else 0
  end as kolektor_new
from sample
order by createdat desc;
```

Output should look something like:

| kolektor | nama | createdat | kolektor_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ex5 | 2023-03-21 | 0 |
| 6 | ex4 | 2023-03-20 | 0 |
| 5 | ex3 | 2023-03-19 | 0 |
| 3 | ex2 | 2023-03-18 | 3 |
| 3 | ex1 | 2023-03-17 | 3 |
| 3 | jojon | 2023-03-10 | 3 |
| 3 | maman suraman | 2023-03-01 | 3 |
| 5 | maman suraman | 2023-02-28 | 5 |
| 3 | Dadang Suradang | 2023-02-23 | 3 |

You can also use `CURRENT_DATE - 1` if you need "one day before today".